# Visual C++ Outlook automation

Tags: c++

I want to automate some maintenance in Public Folders in Exchange with a VS C++ console application. I use VS Community 2017 and Outlook 2016 (with Exchange 2016).

After much searching I created a small application with the following relevant lines:

```
#import "C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/OFFICE16/mso.dll" no_namespace \
rename("DocumentProperties", "OlkDocProps") rename("RGB", "OlkRGB")
    #import "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office16\\msoutl.olb" \
rename_namespace("Outlook") \
rename("Folder", "OlkFolder") rename("CopyFile", "OlkCopyFile") \
rename("GetOrganizer", "GetOrganizerAE") rename("PlaySound", "OlkPlaySound")
```

and

```
_ApplicationPtr spApp( "Outlook.Application");
```

On compile I got loads of errors by Intellisense on the `mso.tlh` and `msoutl.tlh`, which I ignored (370 times "Forward declaration of enum type is nonstandard"). I got some errors on the `#import` lines, which I fixed with extra renames.

Now the application builds, but produces an exception where `spAPP` is declared and constructed:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF8879D5549 in DelDoubleMail.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000015F3F0EFF0. occurred
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Use try catch and get the error with _com_error.

Comment: _com_error contains __vfptr = `[0] = 0x00007ff63f801811 {DelDoubleMail.exe!_com_error::`vector deleting destructor'(unsigned int)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause: a call CoInitializeEx() was missing before the sApp was created.

@Karthik: thank you for your suggestion, tinkering with different catch actions finally gave me the information I needed.